# Manejar archivos con C

Tags: c

estoy aprendiendo a programar en C, y estaba aprendiendo como manejar archivos, y al escribir un código y ejecutarlo, se imprimía un caracter extraño luego de el salto de línea, que es el último caracter que se debería leer. Tal vez se trate de el EOF. No lo sé, que opinan:

```
int main()
{
    char Datos[30]; // Creación de una variable que servirá para guardar los datos leídos de el archivo
    char Texto[30] = "numero = 5\nprint(numero)"; // Texto que se guardará en el archivo
    char Caracter_Actual;
    int Contador = 0;

    FILE *Archivo = fopen(test.py, "w+"); // Apertura de un archivo

    fprintf(Archivo, "%s\n", Texto); // Escritura de un archivo

    rewind(Archivo); // Mover el cursor hasta el inicio del archivo
    while(!(feof(Archivo)))
    {
        Caracter_Actual = fgetc(Archivo); // Lectura de un archivo
        Datos[Contador] = Caracter_Actual; // Añade el caracter a una cadena
        Contador += 1;
    }

    printf("%s", Datos);

    fclose(Archivo); // Cierre de un archivo

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te falta colocar un cero al final de `Datos`. Asi: `Datos[Contador] = 0;`. Como falta, el `printf` sigue imprimiendo hasta encontrar alguno por ahí.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle está en que `feof` reporta fin de archivo **después** de que falla la lectura.

La solución es primero leer, luego preguntar. Entonces, leemos un caracter antes de entrar al `while`, y leemos los siguientes al final de cada iteración.

Además agregamos un cero al final para termina la cadena leída.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Datos[30]; // Creación de una variable que servirá para guardar los datos leídos de el archivo
    char Texto[30] = "numero = 5\nprint(numero)"; // Texto que se guardará en el archivo
    char Caracter_Actual;
    int Contador = 0;

    FILE *Archivo = fopen("test.py", "w+"); // Apertura de un archivo

    fprintf(Archivo, "%s\n", Texto); // Escritura de un archivo
    rewind(Archivo); // Mover el cursor hasta el inicio del archivo

    Caracter_Actual = fgetc(Archivo); // Leer primero, pregunta EOF despues
    while(!(feof(Archivo)))
    {
        Datos[Contador] = Caracter_Actual; // Añade el caracter a una cadena
        Contador += 1;
        printf("contador %i %c\n", Contador, Caracter_Actual);
        Caracter_Actual = fgetc(Archivo); // Lectura de un archivo
    }

    Datos[Contador] = 0;
    printf("%s", Datos);

    fclose(Archivo); // Cierre de un archivo

    return 0;
}
```

produce:

```
contador 1 n
contador 2 u
contador 3 m
contador 4 e
contador 5 r
contador 6 o
contador 7  
contador 8 =
contador 9  
contador 10 5
contador 11 

contador 12 p
contador 13 r
contador 14 i
contador 15 n
contador 16 t
contador 17 (
contador 18 n
contador 19 u
contador 20 m
contador 21 e
contador 22 r
contador 23 o
contador 24 )
contador 25 

numero = 5
print(numero)
```